# converte de vb para c#

Tags: c#, vba

Tenho este código em vb, preciso dele em c#. Em vb crie um código novo cada vez que esta executado, em c# coloca sempre o mesmo código "000011".

```
Public Function CalculaNovoCodBarras() As String

Dim lista As New StdBELista
Dim res As String
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim MaxArt As String
MaxArt = "00001"
flag = False
On Error GoTo erro

Do
    Set lista = BSO.Consulta("Select substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5) as MaxArtigo FROM ARTIGO where substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5) = '" & MaxArt & "'")
    If lista.NoFim Then
        res = GetCodPaisEmpresa & MaxArt
        res = res & CalculaDigitoEAN13(res)
        flag = True
    Else
        MaxArt = Format(MaxArt + 1, "00000")
    End If
Loop While flag = False
CalculaNovoCodBarras = res

 Exit Function
 erro:
 MsgBox Err.Description
End Function
```

C#

```
public string CalculaNovoCodBarras()
    {
        StdBELista lista = new StdBELista();
        string res = "";
        bool flag = false;
        string MaxArt = "00001";
        //  MaxArt = "00001";
        //flag = false;

        do
        {
            lista = BSO.Consulta("Select substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5) as MaxArtigo FROM ARTIGO where substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5) = '" + MaxArt + "'");
            if (lista.NoFim())
            {
                res = GetCodPaisEmpresa() + MaxArt;
                res = res + CalculaDigitoEAN13();
                flag = true;
            }

            else
                MaxArt = String.Format(MaxArt + 1, "00000");
        }
        while (flag == false);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Sempre informe o erro e que linha que ocorre o erro :)

Comment: Não esta a dar erro , em vb esta a gerar um código novo, sequencial com o formato de 5 dígitos cada vez que esta a ser executado em c# esta a dar o mesmo código com 6 dígitos.

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Você quer incrementar `MaxArt` e preencher com `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer incrementar o valor que está vindo como "000001" e preencher com o zeros novamente, você deve converter o valor para inteiro e utilizar o `PadLeft()` para o preenchimento. Se você tentar realizar a soma com uma `string` e um inteiro, a operação não será realizada e o resultado será uma simples concatenação.

```
string MaxArt = "00001";
//MaxArt == "00002"
MaxArt = (int.Parse(MaxArt) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Comment: Quero incrementar MaxArt mas ter sempre o formato de 5 dígitos

Comment: Então faça o Pad com 5 coringas... Mas isso vai funcionar atá você chegar em 99999

Comment: @Aliona Era essa a sua dúvida? Viu a edição na resposta?

Comment: Sim , obrigada.

Comment: Então, você deveria marcar essa como "aceitar resposta" e apague a sua outra por que ela não é uma resposta de fato e não tem muita relevância para outro usuário que enfrente um problema parecido no futuro.

Answer (score 0):

O código final ficou assim

```
    public string CalculaNovoCodBarras()
    {
        StdBELista lista = new StdBELista();
        string res = "";
        bool flag;
        string MaxArt = "00001";
        flag = true;

        do
        {
            lista = BSO.Consulta("Select substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5) as MaxArtigo FROM ARTIGO where substring(Artigo.codbarras,8,5)= '" + MaxArt + "'");
            if (lista.NoFim())
            {

                res = GetCodPaisEmpresa() + MaxArt;
                res = res + CalculaDigitoEAN13(res);
                flag = false;
                break;
            }

            else

                MaxArt = (int.Parse(MaxArt) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');


            flag = true;
            continue;
        }
        while (flag);

        return res;
    }
```